# How to get date of tomorrow in magento2

Tags: magento2, date

How can I get date of tomorrow in Magento2?
I can use below code to get current date but I couldn't fetch the date of tomorrow.

```
// $this->datetime \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime $datetime
// $this->timezone \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $timezone   

 $currentDay = $this->timezone->date($this->datetime->date('+1day'))->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 5):

Use this below code to get date of tomorrow :

### Dependency Method :

```
protected $date;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime $date
    ...
){
    ...
    $this->date = $date;
    ...
}

public function getNextDate()
{
    $date = $this->date->date('Y-m-d');
    $nextdate = $this->date->date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date." +1 days"));
    return $nextdate;
}
```

### Object Manager Method :

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$objDate = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime');
$date = $objDate->date('Y-m-d');
$nextdate = $objDate->date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date." +1 days"));
echo $date."<br/>";
echo $nextdate."<br/>";
```

**Note : Don't use object manager directly. Use dependency method.**

[Reference](https://www.rohanhapani.com/how-to-add-days-to-date-in-magento-2/)

Answer (score 0):

Use simple php

```
 $datetime = new DateTime('tomorrow');
 echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```